# how does hotspot Serviceability Agent deal with GOT in elf files?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

AFAIK, the Serviceability Agent can access target JVM's global variables by parsing its elf file to get variables' virtual address.

However, global variables loaded from `.so` file will be redirect by **GOT** when `.so` is compiled with `-fPIC` in shared mode. How does Serviceability Agent handles that situation? Does it need to lookup **GOT**?

Comment: It finds the symbol offset from ELF file and adds it to the actual load address of `libjvm.so`

Comment: @apangin but for those global variables with external linkage, their address are not resolved until *.so file is loaded. And those variables are redirected by GOT, not simply adding load address.

Comment: What do you think is a "resolved address"? It's the offset of a symbol plus the actual address of `rw` segment of the mapped library, which you can find from `/proc/[pid]/maps`.

Comment: @apangin the key point is that global variables loaded from  a dynamic library are actaully not stored in that library's mapped segment. see [this explanation](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20214) for GOT

Comment: @apangin library's global variabes's true address are stored in the GOT, which is irrelevant with the `rw` segment of that mapped library

Comment: Some functionality of my [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/tree/got) project involves parsing ELF, reading JVM globals, and patching GOT entries. So, believe it or not, I do know how GOT works. What I don't understand though, is the point of asking a question on Stack Overflow, when you already have your own notion of the subject, automatically rejecting any hint that doesn't fit this notion.

Comment: Anyways, GOT is needed to access *imported* symbols. When you know that a particular symbol is *exported* by libjvm.so, you lookup it directly in libjvm.so. Serviceability Agent runs in a completely different process, so this linking/importing procedure doesn't apply at all. SA just looks where the symbol is defined and reads it from there.

Comment: @apangin to calarify it , I'm not rejecting any hints that obeys my notion, but expecting to figure out where I maybe misunderstood, that cause the  inconsistency between my notion and reality.

Comment: @apangin  yes, the SA runs on the client JVM, not target JVM. However, client JVM needs to access target JVM's address space.  So do you mean that target JVM does not need to load libjvm.so? Only the SA client does? I used to think the libjvm.so is part of target JVM. And client JVM use libjvm.so to resolve target JVM's actual layout of libjvm.so

Comment: @apangin To summarize, my key point is that the runtime address of symbols expoted by libjvm.so cannot be known until libjvm.so is loaded by target JVM. Because AFAIK, those global symbols in elf use GOT to store their real address, and the address stored in GOT is not just adding segment base with offset. However the source code of JVM does seem to regard it as base with offset, which confused me a lot.

Comment: *"runtime address of symbols expoted by libjvm.so cannot be known until libjvm.so is loaded by target JVM"* - Yes, obviously, but this has nothing to do with GOT. Answering to your original question, SA does not deal with GOT at all. As I've told above, it finds the actual base address of the target libjvm.so by parsing `/proc/[pid]/maps`, and symbol offsets - by parsing ELF structure of libjvm.so.

Comment: @apangin thanks. Maybe I misunderstood something. Once I've read a book saying when an excecutable reference global variables in *.so. that exectable will allocate directly in .bss segment, and later when so file is load, the variable will be redirected to .bss segment to avoid confict.

Comment: @apangin I've been using your async_profiler, which is an excellent tool. I'm curious that does async profiler use `ptrace` to get all stack infos showed in flame graph? And does that have impact on target jvm? Because `ptrace_attach` will stop target process.

Comment: I'm afraid, this has gone too far from the original topic. Regarding async-profiler, please create a separate question here on Stack Overflow or start a discussion on github. Async-profiler does not use ptrace.